# How to display add button at last element after delete last row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add some more fields with add and remove buttons, when I delete the last record add button must be present at the last element after deleting.

```
<div id="cont">
    <p>
        <label>Contact No : </label>
        <select>
            <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
            <option value="Phone">Land Line</option>
            <option value="Phone">Fax</option>
        </select> 
        <input type="text" name="website" value="" />
        <input type="button" value="+" id="addcontact1" />
    </p>
</div>
```

This is a fiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/8dq15j2y/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8dq15j2y/

Comment: Edit the question instead of adding to comment.

Comment: See your question already has a downvote. If you want proper answers please format the question properly and define what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Note: ID of an element must be unique, so use class instead

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#cont');
  var i = $('#cont p').size() + 1;

  $('#cont').on('click', '.addcontact1', function() {
    $('<p style="margin-left:150px;"><select><option value="Phone">Phone</option><option value="Land-Line">Land-Line</option><option value="Fax">Fax</option></select><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="" /> <a href="#" class="remScnt">remove</a> <input type="button" value="+" class="addcontact1"></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    $(this).hide();
    return false;

  });

  $('#cont').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).closest('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    $('#cont p').last().find('.addcontact1').show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont">
  <p>
    <label>Contact No :</label>
    <select>
      <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
      <option value="Phone">Land Line</option>
      <option value="Phone">Fax</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="website" value="" />
    <input type="button" value="+" class="addcontact1" />
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Using css: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k7t86pkx/3/

Answer (score 0):

Add + button after P tag and Replace $('#addcontact1').show(); to $('#addcontact1').hide();

Answer (score 0):

you can insert after the line
$(this).parents('p').remove();  with code bellow:

```
 $('#cont p:last').children('#addcontact1').show();
```